# Passing a parameter to Html.ActionLink when the model is IEnumerable<T>

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I really hope someone can help me with this somewhat simple thing I am trying to do. I am very new to MVC and am still trying to get my head around it!

I have a controller called Submission that gets passed a company id so I can keep track of which company we are working in.

```
http://myurl/Submission/Index/1
```

The code for this view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Reports.Models.Submission>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</p>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.ContactName) | @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {      id=item.submissionID }) </p>
}
```

I can see how I pass my submissionId for my "Edit" link as I am within a loop for the model. This works fine.

My problem is that I cannot add a parameter to my "Create New" Actionlink e.g.

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create",new {id=Model.[No options appear here!]}</p>
```

I think this is because I have my model declared as IENumerable at the top, but I need it like this to loop through my companies for the edit link. Basically it looks like I need two versions of the Model but I know this is not possible. Anyone know what I can do here??

Comment: What does the "Create New" view and controller code look like? Do you need id for that page?

Comment: append "@" before should solve your query

Comment: Currently my create link goes to http://url/Submission/Create - but  I want to take across the ID (same one as in the Edit link) to the Create page. I can manually get it to work by doing this: url/Submission/Create?ReportNameid=1 - I just cannot get the Actionlink from Index to allow me add it!

Comment: There's something I'm not getting with all of this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume when you have `url/Submission/Index/x` where `x` is the company id, you want to generate this as the Create link: `url/Submission/Create?CompanyId=x`.  I'd suggest changing the model class to something like below, which contains `CompanyID` and `Submissions` property.

```
public class SubmissionIndexModel
{
    public SubmissionIndexModel()
    {
        this.Submissions = new List<Submission>();
    }

    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public List<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }
}
```

Here's what your controller code should look like

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    SubmissionIndexModel model = new SubmissionIndexModel();
    model.CompanyID = id;
    model.Submissions = (from n in db.Submissions where n.reportNameID == id select n).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

Your view code should look like below, you can pass `Model.CompanyID` to the Create action link and enumerate through `Model.Submissions` to generate the Edit links.

```
@model SubmissionIndexModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { CompanyId = Model.CompanyID })</p>

@foreach (var item in Model.Submissions)
{
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactName) | @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.submissionID }) </p>
}
```

Comment: This looks promising! There is a BUT: I am having trouble getting the submissions using syntax I was using before:

model.Submissions = from n in db.Submissions
                                where n.reportNameID == id
                                select n; - it says it cannot implicitly convert the type?

Comment: See the updated answer, you just need to add `.ToList()`

Comment: Wow - you have been very helpful - thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If your code looks exactly as in your post, then it's a problem that Visual Studio and Razor cannot resolve. You can, though. Your code looks like this:

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new {id=Model.[No options appear here!]}</p>
```

Please check your code once again and proof that the end parenthesis `)` is missing. If it is, then simply closing the parenthesis will get you your Intellisense back. That is, your code should look like this:

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new {id=Model.[No options appear here!]})</p>
                                                                                    ^
                                                                 look for this _____|
```

Comment: Thanks - nothing to do with the code I have built the project and no issues appear.

Comment: @user3593088, you won't be able to spot something wrong. The parser fails to identify that as a syntax error. It will only be visible once you run your view. If you don't close the parenthesis, Razor will not be able to understand that you have a function call and will render that as plain text instead of dynamically run it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a ViewModel instead of using IEnumerable on your cshtml for starters.

**View Model**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SubmissionVm {
    public IEnumerable<Reports.Models.Submission> submissions { get; set; }
    public int MaxId {
        return submissions.OrderByDescending(s => s.submissionID).FirstOrDefault().submissionID;
    }
}
```

On your cshtml, in your Create New link you are going after Model., but there are no properties there to look at, because Model is an IEnumerable. Maybe you are trying to get the next id, or the top id in the Enumerable? So the MaxId property above will give  you the highest submissionID in your IEnumerable. Then you can modify your Create New link as such.

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create",new {id=Model.MaxId})</p>
```

On your controller, you will want to maybe increment this number by one, or something to change it from the MaxId

Comment: I have looked into this yes. The ID I need to get is the current ReportNameId (the one I have already been able to get inside the loop for the Edit link)

Comment: but it is an IEnumerable, so it could be many submissions there. How do you know which one you want to use on the Create link? Are you only expecting one submission on that page?

Comment: I don't want to loop through to get the Id. I want to re-use the Id http://myurl/Submission/Index/1 at the end of that URL and take it across to Submission/Create. I can manually type this in url/Submission/Create?ReportNameid=1 and it works!

Comment: i understand that manually typing it works. I am just trying to figure out what item to use from the IEnumerable. What if there are 5 items in there? How do you know which id you want to use?

Comment: I have accepted ekad's answer - thanks all for you help